# Mongoose: update an element of an array of a specific document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having a collection of documents called 'company'.

company 1 -

```
{ 
  _id: '1',
  data:[
    {_id:'11', value: 'emp11'},
    {_id:'12', value: 'emp12'}
  ]
}
```

company 2-

```
 { 
  _id: '2',
  data:[
    {_id:'21', value: 'emp21'},
    {_id:'22', value: 'emp22'}
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update value 'emp11' to 'emp99'.
I'm following this approach-

```
companyModel.findById('1', function(err, company) {
    return company.data.update(
        {_id: '11'},
        {$set: {value: 'emp99'}}
    );
});
```

I'm able to get the company but after that it's showing an error-

```
company.data.update is not a function
```

Please suggest a possible solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
companyModel.update(
  { "_id" : :"1", "data._id": "11" }, 
  { "$set": { "data.$.value": "emp99" }}, 
  function(err, company) {
    console.log(company)
})
```

There is no **need to use findById**, you can use this directly.
In mongo update you need to search for both the document and the field you want to update.
The field you want to update is essential as it is used to locate the position of the array when you use $.

However you can do it as following also :

```
companyModel.findById('1', function(err, company) {
    for(var i =0; i< company.data.length; i++)
        if(company.data._id === "11")
            break;
    if(i<company.data.length)
        company.data[i].value = 'emp99'
    company.save()
});
```

Comment: Great...! It worked.....thanks a lot. Can you pls suggest where to learn about mongoose queries other than official docs.

Comment: I have used a lot of mongodb, so it comes by experience and docs are really good. MongoDB docs provide examples which are helpful in learning.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

```
db.company.update({
    _id: "1",
    data: {
        $elemMatch: {
            value: 'emp11'
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        'data.$.value': 'emp99'
    }
})
```

Comment: Please add comments to explain what the problem was and how your code snippet shows the right solution.

Comment: Basically what you are doing is passing in the data you want to update into the first query object. `data: {
        $elemMatch: {
            value: 'emp11'
        }
    }` is basically saying "In the data array (or whatever your data is called) match the element with the value "emp11."  Then in the `$set` part of the query we're doing `$set: `"data.$.value": "emp99"`` What this is basically saying is set the data item to the new value "emp99." How it finds that particular data item is by the use of the mongoose `$` operator which finds the correct elements index, under the hood.